# It is possible run npm script and redirect to stdout

Tags: npm, stdout, stderr, npm-scripts

I have the following two npm scripts:

**package.json**

```json
"scripts": {
  "check:coverage": "npm test && http-server -so -p 9000 coverage/lcov-report",
  "test": "jest --coverage --verbose"
}
```

My idea it's that when i run the command: `npm run check:coverage`, the command `http-server` would run after either the first script run success (all the test passed) or not (one or more test are failing).
But when the test are failing the Errors doesn't permit that the `http-server` was run.

So my question is:
 **It's possible redirect the errors to the stdout for run http-server independently of the results of the script `npm test`**?

PS: I've tried using the `|` for run both task in parallel but if the suite test takes too long time for run when http-server open the page, the coverage report is not ready at this time.